# Setting IBus Property in MVC Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, aop, structuremap, nservicebus, nservicebus3

I'm trying to send a command from a filter in my MVC4 project to my command processor.

The problem:
I can't get an NServiceBus instance in the filter to fill.

The components:

- ASP.NET MVC 4
- NServiceBus version 3
- StructureMap

The Attribute/Filter:

```
namespace AMS.WebApp.Filters
{
    public class AMSAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public IBus Bus { get; set; }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            bool accessGranted = false;

            accessGranted = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);


            // arbitrary command, don't worry about it
            // Why is Bus still null?
            var requestAccess = new RequestingAccess();
            Bus.Send("AMS.AccessControl.CommandProcessor", requestAccess);

            //if(isAdmin)
            //  accessGranted = true;

            #if DEBUG
                accessGranted = true;
            #endif

            return accessGranted;
        }
    }
}
```

The IOC Code:

```
using AMS.WebApp.Filters;
using NServiceBus;
using StructureMap;
namespace AMS.WebApp.DependencyResolution {
    public static class IoC {
        public static IContainer Initialize() {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                        {
                            x.Scan(scan =>
                                    {
                                        scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                                        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                    });

                            //This doesn't work
                            //x.SetAllProperties(y => y.OfType<IBus>());  

                            //Neither does this                            
                            //x.ForConcreteType<AMSAuthorizeAttribute>()
                            // .Configure
                            // .Setter<IBus>(a => a.Bus)
                            // .IsTheDefault();
                        });
            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, my attempt to bypass structuremap completely by passing in the bus instance from the controller resulted in:

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
```

At this point I'm pretty sure its something awkward with attributes/filters and structuremap, but I'm not really sure what that is.

WARNING: the accepted answer does not fix the actual problem of getting nservicebus in an action filter, but it does address how to get DI in an action filter. See [ASP.NET MVC4 NServiceBus Attribute/Filter StructureMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196652/asp-net-mvc4-nservicebus-attribute-filter-structuremap) for the Nservicebus specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this post.  I think this is what you're looking for.

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters/

Edit:

I think you have two different issues here.

1. Using DI on a filter
2. Configuring DI on NServiceBus

Can you please post your code which initializes NServiceBus for StructureMap?

You are looking for somthing like this:

Configure.With().StructureMapBuilder()

Comment: Interesting, I think this does it. I'll try it tomorrow at work and mark the answer if it works. Thanks!

Comment: This works on a sample project I created. I removed the stuff in the article and the setter injection doesn't work, add it, and the setter injection works. Unfortunately, NServiceBus throws a fit with the extra configuration: StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.ISubscriptionStorage, NServiceBus.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c

Comment: As John states below, make sure you explicitly tell NServiceBus to use StructureMap.  From your code, I don't see this step being performed.  If you skip this step, NSB will use it's default which I think is AutoFac.  This would explain why StructureMap don't find the NServiceBus interfaces.