# ASP.NET MVC4 NServiceBus Attribute/Filter StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, nservicebus, nservicebus3

I'm having issues getting an instance of IBus in an action filter (attribute).

From [Setting IBus Property in MVC Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179547/setting-ibus-property-in-mvc-filter), I know that DI and action filters don't play nice, and I got them play nice using the accepted answer. The problem is that getting DI and action filters to play nice breaks NServiceBus.

That same question had a suggestion by John to look at the video store solution to see how to get it done. There are two problems with that answer:

1. It totally ignores the fact that I'm using StructureMap.
2. More importantly, using that sample, when I added my own derived authorize filter (see below), the IBus instance is still not being filled.

This is a guess on my part, but I don't think the baked in DI container that NServiceBus has can handle DI into an action filter, either.

```
//NOTE:
//I added a Filters folder to the project, and stuck this class in there
//This filter will disable authentication when debugging
//Add the attribute to the home controller, and
//If you put a break point at the beginning, IBus doesn't get filled

using NServiceBus;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace VideoStore.ECommerce.Filters
{
    public class AMSAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public IBus Bus { get; set; }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            bool accessGranted = false;

            accessGranted = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

            //if(isAdmin)
            //  accessGranted = true;

#if DEBUG
            accessGranted = true;
#endif

            return accessGranted;
        }
    }
}
```

When I follow the steps specified in [Setting IBus Property in MVC Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179547/setting-ibus-property-in-mvc-filter), I get this error `StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.ISubscriptionStorage, NServiceBus.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c`

Comment: Have you told NServiceBus to use StructureMap as its internal container? See http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/852357

Comment: yes, everything works fine as long as i don't try to use NServiceBus in a filter. I can get NServiceBus to work with StructureMap, and I can get StructureMap to do Property Injection on a filter, but trying to get StructureMap to inject NServiceBus in an action filter does not work.

Comment: In the mean time, I've set my filters to global and selectively apply them to the controller and actions I want, instead of using attributes, therefor skipping through the entire problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because filter attributes don't play nice with dependency injection, you may find it's easier just to do this within your filter:

```
private readonly IBus bus = Configure.Instance.Builder.Build<IBus>();
```

Comment: wouldn't that require me to have a reference to structuremap or DI container of choice in each of the filter definitions?

Comment: It shouldn't. NServiceBus will use StructureMap (or whatever you configure) internally, but you can get a reference to the singleton IBus through the NServiceBus API no matter how it was built.

Comment: Oh, I thought Configure was StructureMap specific namespace. I'll try this tomorrow and see how it works. Are there any drawbacks to building the IBus like this?

Comment: You're not actually building it when you execute this, you're just asking the Builder to return a reference to you. IBus is configured as a singleton so you're always receiving a reference to the same instance.